# how to add scrollbar in html component in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using html component to show some html content in flutter like this:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
            16.0,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () => launchUrl(item.link),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      item.title == "" ? "Comment" : item.title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (item.domain != "")
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        Channel channel = await Repo.fetchChannelItem(int.parse(item.subSourceId));
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChannelPage(item: channel)),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        item.domain,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      )),
                ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: item.author,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: " ${String.fromCharCode(8226)} ",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: item.ago,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (item.content != "")
                Html(
                  data: item.content,
                  style: {
                    "body": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                    ),
                  },
                  onLinkTap: (url) => launchUrl(url),
                ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item.isFav == 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav", FavStatus.UNFAV),
                              ),
                            if (item.isFav != 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                                onPressed: () => touchFav("fav", FavStatus.FAV),
                              ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${item.favCount}",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item.isUpvote == 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                onPressed: () => touchUpvote("unupvote", UpvoteStatus.UNUPVOTE),
                              ),
                            if (item.isUpvote != 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                                onPressed: () => touchUpvote("upvote", UpvoteStatus.UPVOTE),
                              ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${item.upvoteCount}",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Feather.share_2,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => handleShare(id: item.id, title: item.title, postUrl: item.link),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ))
```

when the content is very long, I want to show the progress of the content, what should I do to add a scrollbar in html component so that I could known the reading progress?

Answer (score 2):

Do you encapsulate your `Html` widget inside a `Scrollbar > SingleChildScrollView`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Html(
            data: """
<h1>Demo Page</h1>
<p>Selfish strong christianity ascetic fearful spirit deceptions justice mountains decrepit. Reason fearful depths chaos truth will justice reason battle pious marvelous zarathustra ocean deceptions. Free battle oneself right christian reason holiest god ocean society faithful free decieve inexpedient.</p>
<p>Oneself deceptions chaos derive merciful evil holiest. Spirit moral christianity mountains eternal-return decrepit of salvation philosophy decrepit. Depths reason madness ultimate burying law superiority strong noble. Enlightenment prejudice depths justice love overcome oneself truth disgust. Ascetic eternal-return love convictions ascetic disgust ubermensch against self faithful decrepit moral endless play. Against reason dead madness virtues truth enlightenment insofar moral pinnacle ubermensch intentions.</p>
<p>Depths dead faithful superiority morality joy abstract depths joy zarathustra eternal-return holiest war. Christianity eternal-return pinnacle snare enlightenment derive transvaluation good sea inexpedient reason pious evil ultimate. Enlightenment joy inexpedient hatred aversion deceptions marvelous inexpedient ultimate.</p>
""",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want the `Scrollbar` to be always visible, set `isAlwaysShown: true`. This will require a `ScrollController` to be defined on both the `Scrollbar` and the `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _scrollController = useScrollController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        controller: _scrollController,
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: Html(
            data: """
<h1>Demo Page</h1>
<p>Selfish strong christianity ascetic fearful spirit deceptions justice mountains decrepit. Reason fearful depths chaos truth will justice reason battle pious marvelous zarathustra ocean deceptions. Free battle oneself right christian reason holiest god ocean society faithful free decieve inexpedient.</p>
<p>Oneself deceptions chaos derive merciful evil holiest. Spirit moral christianity mountains eternal-return decrepit of salvation philosophy decrepit. Depths reason madness ultimate burying law superiority strong noble. Enlightenment prejudice depths justice love overcome oneself truth disgust. Ascetic eternal-return love convictions ascetic disgust ubermensch against self faithful decrepit moral endless play. Against reason dead madness virtues truth enlightenment insofar moral pinnacle ubermensch intentions.</p>
<p>Depths dead faithful superiority morality joy abstract depths joy zarathustra eternal-return holiest war. Christianity eternal-return pinnacle snare enlightenment derive transvaluation good sea inexpedient reason pious evil ultimate. Enlightenment joy inexpedient hatred aversion deceptions marvelous inexpedient ultimate.</p>
""",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it seem not work. I pasted the full code of page.@Thierry